# Which PHP CMS/Framework to use in this specific situation?

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

I've consulted various websites, though I seem to drown in information, not finding the right answer for my question. I am looking for a PHP CMS/Framework which will help me develop next project.

I do want users, and usergroups, having different rights depending on the group. 
I don't want to have a specific separation between back-end and front-end. 
Pages are rendered depending on what rights the user has on that specific page/parts of the page. 
I need a template system, easy managing of layout (basic layout, derived layouts, etc.). 
I need to manage content for informative pages (not often changing).
I need to manage news/updates (often changing).
I need a photo album and the ability to easily manage this and to link it to news and updates.
I need to be able to build a custom maintenance page, for specific information for certain events.
I need some info to be edited live and be updated immediately without refreshing the browser, with some kind of notification that gives information on what has been deleted/added/changed. 
I want it to be light weight. I want only the things I need visible (or been able to removed), so it is very straight forward for the users, since there will be no training needed to be able to use the website and its features.

Is there a CMS/Framework that will suit my needs, or will I need to start from scratch and write my own?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah all your requirements can be fullfilled by Joomla ,i am sure.

Comment: I looked up Joomla. It is a CMS? Is front-end and back-end separated then? I need website structure not to be separated by front and back-end, just different behavior depending on which group the user is in.